# Checking connection to Kafka Aws Msk cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, apache-kafka

Suppose one is in a Spring boot microservice and one connects to a Amazon msk cluster. The configurations for connecting to the cluster are mentioned in the bootstrap yml within the microservice resources directory. The sasl scram combination is used to authenticate the service to the cluster.
Now one wants to test that connection to the kafka cluster has succeeded during microservice startup else stop the microservice from starting up.
Is there a way to write java code to test this connectivity between service and cluster and throw an exception as a log and prevent the service from starting up and log the exact exception for debugging purposes. Thanks!!

Comment: http://www.masterspringboot.com/apache-kafka/how-to-monitor-kafka-using-jmx/

Comment: Thanks for the link but am looking for something at startup when a spring boot application starts up. The aws msk configs are in bootstrap and if it doesnt connect then service does not start up is the requirement. So the focus is not on monitoring the kafka topic but on stopping service from startup on failing kafka connections and other kafka related failures.